# How to I return a case record with latest date using SQL

Tags: sql

[image]

I want a query that returns a record set of the shaded rows from the table above for each unique case_id by the latest data_level_assinged value.  I tried something like this:

```
SELECT case_id, level, date_level_assigned
FROM table
SORT BY case_id, date_level_assigned DESC;
```

From reading it looks like I need to use an aggregate function like MAX(data_level_assinged) but am not sure how to do this.

Comment: a group by with max should help. what is the database?

Comment: Try a window function max(date_level_assigned) over(partition by case_id). I'm not sure which sql you are using.

Comment: SQL has `ORDER BY`, not SORT BY.

Comment: Most people here want sample table date _and the expected result_ as formatted text. (No images, no links.)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.
Using MAX is a good approach.

```
SELECT b.case_id, a.level, b.date_level_assigned FROM tablename a
JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(date_level_assigned) as date_level_assigned, case_id
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY case_id
    ) as b
ON a.case_id = b.case_id AND a.date_level_assigned = b.date_level_assigned
```

You can do it in this way